# Unable to write to log file if python flask app running under apache2 mod_wsgi

Tags: python, flask, logging, apache2, mod-wsgi

When I run the app.py use command line
no issue, the log file will be generated and logged.

but when the py file run by apache wsgi

no log comes out

```
file_log_path = '/var/log/apache2/'
file_log = 'python_app_log.txt'
file_log_full = file_log_path + file_log

logging.basicConfig(filename = file_log_full, level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(funcName)s| %(message)s")

logging.info('Finished init path')

#----- Main-Fucntions ------------------------------------
#-- Set up time ---
logging.info('Main-Fucntions Init...')
tz_utc = tz.tzoffset('UTC Time', 0 * 60)
tz_sql = tz.tzoffset('SQL Server Time', Get_MySQL_TimeZone() * 60)

logging.info(tz_utc)
logging.info('MySQL Server Time zone is ' + tz_sql._name)



#----- Main Process Code must in above--------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
    #app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port = 30443 ,debug = True)
    logging.info('APP RUN Event')
```

Comment: don't you get any error message? Apache may run code as different user, with different privilage, in differen folder, with different environment variables, using different Python version, with different modules. Maybe change privilages for folde `/var/log/apache2`. And if there is some problem then apache should also save some informations in own logs - and it can be useful to see problem in Python code.

Comment: Please, show us the connection code with mysql.